# Where are my windows phone 8.1 wallpapers stored?

Tags: 8.1, windows-10-mobile, personalization, windows-10-upgrade

When I was on Windows phone 8.1 there were lot of system wallpapers. But after upgrading i can found none of them. whenever i go to Wallpaper settings Only few Of the Wallpapers available which had came with upgadation. I thought that those wallpapers were removed but today when I tried to change wallpaper through a 3rd party app and then resetted my wallpaper, It gave me the wallpaper which solely belong to Windows phone 8.1. I still can't see where the wallpaper has stored nor I can have it in my settings. so If the wallpaper is present in the phone then how can I access it?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that those wallpapers are stored in that app only. Means developer has provided those wallpapers in his app.